Understanding the function of .so files in an APP
An app uses .so files, but these are not integrated into the Android APK. They are downloaded after installing the app and after registration and are also updated regularly.
There are different folders in the downloaded data, each of which always contains a .so file and a different number of files (e.g. 11) that have the extension .0000. Perhaps they are related to the shared-object files.
For the sake of interest, I would like to know what is in the files.
Previous attempts: Android-Studio only shows unreadable characters, Editor as well.
JADX shows me the binary code, which unfortunately doesn't really help me either.
Now my question is, what possibility is there to open these files and display them readably?

Files with  ".0000" extension are most likely split archive files. Sometimes, the ".so" files are too big to put in your app all at once. So, instead of one big file, they are split into smaller parts, like pieces of a puzzle. Each piece is named with a number, like .0000, .0001, and so on.
To open and view these files, you need to combine them back into their original form. I didn't know how to do it, so I did some research for you. You can use Command Prompt in Windows to combine them.

Put all the files you need to combine in 1 folder

Open cmd in that folder and use copy command. Like this:
copy /b file.0000 + file.0001 + file.0002 combined_file


After that you should have the file as "combined_file".
Update: If the files have different name but same ".0000" extension, we need to check their size. If they all have different name but same size, there is a chance that they might be from same ".so" file. The best way to ensure this is to check the first few bits. Because they often provide clues about the file type. Once again, I didn't know how to do this, so I found a python script for it.
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        print(f.read(64))  # Read the first 64 bytes

read_file('filename.0000')


Thank you very much for your answer!
However, the files all have the extension .0000, only the file name is different.
In this case, is this also a split main file, or are they all different files that are accessed by the app?

If they all have different name and same .0000 extension, then they are most likely separate files. But you should still look at their size. If they are same size with different name, they could be from same ".so" file.

Please check update.

What is .SO Files :
In a nutshell, .so files is a shared object library which can be loaded and excused during run time. We can leverage C++ native code in Android, and NDK compiles this code into .so files.
Why we need to use .so files:
I think the biggest and direct benefit is you can reduce the size of your app by using .so files combining with your NDK. but, what else?

.so files mechanism is to let developer maximize the leverage of C or C++ code in your current Android app.

A .so file is binary, using so file would be less costly than Java.

The Memory allocation of .so files would not be limited by Dalivik/ART which can avoid OOM in some ways.

Compared with Java, Decompilation of binary code is more difficult in .so files.



Thank you also for your answer!
Is there a way to decompile the .so files?
Are the .0000 files related to the .so files?
